# Deallocate multidimensional array in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

How would I go about destroying a dynamic array of arbitrary size, dimensions, and type?
Will delete[] automatically go down the levels of a two dimensional array or just delete the first level of pointers so the program need to manually iterate over each array level?

Ideally I need a single command (for use in a template class) that will destroy one to four dimensional arrays.  It would also work if there is a way to check the number of dimensions of an array.

I am using dymanic arrays such as double* ar = new double[100];

Comment: Arrays are one dimensional in C++. `delete[]` will delete an array made with `new[]`. If the array is an array of other arrays (possibly of other arrays), this will work fine. Can you expand on what you are concerned about?

Comment: You already received good answers; I'd like however to suggest [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html), maybe you can find it suited for your N-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you instanciate the 2 dimensional array like `new int[10][20]` the `delete[]` will destroy all the array, but if you created it iterating like `myarray[i] = new int[20]` so you will have to iterate again to destroy each dimension.

If you are not sure about how to destroy the array I would recoment you to use the STL vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++ then use `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually iterate over all levels to delete them.
If there is a way to check the dimensions, you can just use that to select the correct destruction process.

Also, why not use vectors ? they are fast and are automatically deallocated when out of scope

Answer (score 0):

Basically `1 new = 1 delete` and `10 new = 10 delete`, so you have to delete everything you allocate, the number of those operation called should be equal.

There's no way of knowing (from compilers/programs point of view) what's the real data pointer, what's just some trash or what is referenced elsewhere (and will be used) and so on.